# What is wrong with the recursive algorithm developed for the below problem?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have tried to solve an algorithmic problem. I have come up with a recursive algorithm to solve the same. This is the link to the problem:

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1178/B

**This problem is not from any contest that is currently going on.**

I have coded my algorithm and had run it on a few test cases, it turns out that it is counting more than the correct amount. I went through my thought process again and again but could not find any mistake. I have written my algorithm (not the code, but just the recursive function I have thought of) below. Can I please know where had I gone wrong -- what was the mistake in my thought process?

Let my recursive function be called as **count**, it takes any of the below three forms as the algorithm proceeds.

> 1. count(i,'o',0) = count(i+1,'o',0) [+ count(i+1,'w',1) --> iff (i)th
>    element of the string is 'o']
> 2. count(i,'w',0) = count(i+1,'w',0) [+ count(i+2,'o',0) --> iff (i)th and (i+1)th elements are both equal to 'v']
> 3. count(i,'w',1) = count(i+1,'w',1) [+ **1** + count(i+2,'w',0) --> iff (i)th and (i+1)th elements are both equal to 'v']

Note: The recursive function calls present inside the [.] (square brackets) will be called iff the conditions mentioned after the arrows are satisfied.)

**Explanation:** The main idea behind the recursive function developed is to count the number of occurrences of the given sequence. The **count** function takes 3 arguments:

argument 1: The index of the string on which we are currently located.

argument 2: The pattern we are looking for (if this argument is 'o' it means that we are looking for the letter 'o' -- i.e. at which index it is there. If it is 'w' it means that we are looking for the pattern 'vv' -- i.e. we are looking for 2 consecutive indices where this pattern occurs.)

argument 3: This can be either 1 or 0. If it is 1 it means that we are looking for the 'vv' pattern, having already found the 'o' i.e. we are looking for the 'vv' pattern shown in bold: vvo**vv**. If it is 0, it means that we are searching for the 'vv' pattern which will be the
beginning of the pattern **vv**ovv (shown in bold.)

I will initiate the algorithm with **count(0,'w',0)** -- it means, we are at the 0th index of the string, we are looking for the pattern 'vv', and this 'vv' will be the prefix of the 'vvovv' pattern we wish to find.

So, the output of **count(0,'w',0)** should be my answer. Now comes the trouble, for the following input: "**vvovooovovvovoovoovvvvovo**" (say input1), my program (which is based on the above algorithm) gives the expected answer(= 50). But, when I just append "**vv**" to the above input to get a new input: "**vvovooovovvovoovoovvvvovovv**" (say input2) and run my algorithm again, I get 135 as the answer, while the correct answer is 75 (this is the answer the solution code returns). Why is this happening? Where had I made an error?

Also, one more doubt is if the output for the input1 is 50, then the output for the input2 should be at least twice right -- because all of the subsequences which were present in the input1, will be present in the input2 too and all of those subsequences can also form a new subsequence with the appended 'vv' -- this means we have at least 100 favourable subsequences right?

P.S. This is the link to the solution code https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/68534

Comment: I have found the mistake, I have made. The 3rd recursion should be this: count(i,'w',1) = count(i+1,'w',1) [+ 1 --> iff (i)th and (i+1)th elements are both equal to 'v']. Because, once we have found the solution, we just need to add 1 (signifying we have got the answer) and stop -- we should not make any recursive call from there, else same subsequences will be counted multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't need recursion or dynamic programming.

The basic idea is to count how many `w`s we have before and after each `o`.

If you have **X** `v`s, it means you have **X - 1** `w`s.

Let's use `vvvovvv` as an example. We know that before and after the `o` we have 3 `v`s, which means 2 `w`s. To evaluate the answer, just multiply 2x2 = 4.

For each `o` we find, we just need to multiply the `w`s before and after it, sum it all and this is our answer.

We can find how many `w`s there are before and after each `o` in linear time.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int convert_v_to_w(int v_count){
    return max(0, v_count - 1);
}

int main(){
    
    string s = "vvovooovovvovoovoovvvvovovvvov";
    int n = s.size();
    
    int wBefore[n];
    int wAfter[n];
    
    int v_count = 0, wb = 0, wa = 0;
    
    //counting ws before each o
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n){
        v_count = 0;
        while(i < n && s[i] == 'v'){
            v_count++;
            i++;
        }
        wb += convert_v_to_w(v_count);
        
        if(i < n && s[i] == 'o'){
            wBefore[i] = wb; 
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    //counting ws after each o
    i = n - 1;
    while(i >= 0){
        v_count = 0;
        while(i >= 0 && s[i] == 'v'){
            v_count++;
            i--;
        }
        wa += convert_v_to_w(v_count);
        
        if(i >= 0 && s[i] == 'o'){
            wAfter[i] = wa; 
        }
        i--;
    }
    
    //evaluating answer by multiplying ws before and after each o
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(s[i] == 'o') ans += wBefore[i] * wAfter[i];
    }

    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

output: `100`

complexity: O(n) time and space

Comment: the idea you have suggested is great! Anyways, I have found the mistake I have made. Thanks for the help!